# Django Filtering error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I have a very simple model object and a very simple view that returns a query to that model object. The problem is that it's returning an error. I've been searching around but didn't find any solution to this. Any help is very appreciated.

Model

```
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill
from django.utils.timezone import now
class Eventos(models.Model):
    '''Eventos d\'a Tasca'''
    nome_do_evento = models.CharField(u'Nome do Evento', max_length=100, unique=False)
    descricao_do_evento = models.CharField(u'Descrição do Evento', max_length=500, unique=False, default="")
    data_do_evento = models.DateField(u'Data do Evento', default=now)
    imagem_do_evento = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagem_do_evento')
    thumbnail_do_evento = ImageSpecField(source='imagem_do_evento',
                                  processors=[ResizeToFill(400, 300, None, False)],
                                  format='JPEG',
                                  options={'quality': 60})
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nome_do_evento
```

View

```
from frontend.models import Eventos
from django.utils.timezone import now
def eventos(request):
    template = loader.get_template('frontend/eventos.html')
    eventos = Eventos.objects.filter(data_do_evento>now).order_by('data_do_evento')
```

This is the error

> eventos =
> Eventos.objects.filter(data_do_evento>now).order_by('data_do_evento')
>
> NameError: global name 'data_do_evento' is not defined

Comment: As ShangWang mentions, Django is trying to evaluate `data_do_evento>now` to a boolean because it does not understand the `>` operator. Hence the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `>` to compare in django query, use `__gt`:

```
eventos = Eventos.objects.filter(data_do_evento__gt=now).order_by('data_do_evento')
```

[django doc about gt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#gt).

Comment: Well, it works! I really feel embarrassed by how dumb I feel right now. Thank you my friend.